# Ebean doesn't create the tables Needed for model inheritance (Play framework)

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean

I have a User class, and three other classes inheriting from it: Employer, Student and Coordinator. This is my User class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    public String username;

    public String password;

    public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder(Long.class, User.class);

    public static User authenticate(String username, String password) {
        return find.where().eq("username", username).eq("password", password).findUnique();
    }
}
```

However, Ebean creates only one table, User, with all the data from the 4 classes combined. How can I make Ebean create one user table, one employer table etc.?

That's what I expected Ebean to do when I added the @Inheritance annotation. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EbeanORM does not support InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS.  It is an outstanding enhancement request.

Comment: So what I want is actually not possible with Ebean? Is my only option to have a huge user table with lots of holes (since I have to merge all the data from employer, student, user and coordinator) as soon as I add data?